# Tesseract Error

Tags: python-3.x, tesseract

I am using `tesseract` to extract text out of images.
I use the `pytesseract` package.
When I run the `image_to_string()` function I am getting the following error:

```
TessaractError : (1, '')
```

What may be the reason for this?

This is my code:

```
import pytesseract as pyt
text = pyt.image_to_string(Image.open("Figure_3.png"))
print(text)
```

Thanks for your help.